# PhpStorm doesn't recognize package.json name of local directories

Tags: node.js, react-native, phpstorm

I'm using ReactNative and I have package.json in my local directories so I can have easier imports.

Example:
I have src/components folder and I want to import all components as :

```
import Button from 'components/Button;
```

and not use relative path as

```
import Button from '../../../components/Button;
```

I created package.json file in my components folder with name 'components' and now I can access Button component as needed.

But, there is problem with PhpStorm. PhpStorm doesn't recognize this as valid path. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

This React native hack for specifying absolute paths (not officially documented anywhere, as far as I can tell) had never been supported. If you miss this feature, please follow [WEB-23221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221) for updates. You can try creating a dummy webpack config like it's suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221#focus=streamItem-27-2719626.0-0 and specifying a path to it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** as a workaround.

Another workaround (if you aren't renaming paths, just making it shorter) is marking a parent folder of `components` directory as **Resource root** (note: not the subdirectory itself, but its parent dir!)